# Exacly search in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can search text in javascript only if is match perfectly. For example I have this structure:

```
<ul class="item-options">
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>item Name</li>
    <li>product 1</li>
    <li>Item Description</li>
    <li>product description</li>
    <li>Additional Info</li>
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Color</li>
    <li>Red</li>
</ul>

<ul class="item-options">
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>item Name Blue</li>
    <li>product 2</li>
    <li>Item Description</li>
    <li>product2 description</li>
    <li>Additional Info</li>
    <li>-----</li>
    <li>Color</li>
    <li>Blue</li>
</ul>

<ul class="item-options">
    <li>Third Item</li>
    <li>item Name Purple</li>
    <li>product 3</li>
    <li>Item Description</li>
    <li>-------</li>
    <li>Additional Info</li>
    <li>-----</li>
    <li>Color</li>
    <li>------</li>
</ul>
```

For example I want to check if the text **item Name** exist in the page then if the **item Name** text exist remove associated children. So for the first **item Name** I need to remove only the color:

```
<li>Color</li>
<li>Red</li>
```

Then if **item Name Blue** text exist I need to remove associated children

```
<li>Additional Info</li>
<li>-----</li>
```

and if the third **item Name Purple** text exist then remove associated children:

```
<li>Item Description</li>
<li>-------</li>
<li>Additional Info</li>
<li>-----</li>
<li>Color</li>
<li>------</li>
```

I create this script but for example the name **Color** is deleted everywhere. Even if in the **item Name** or in **item Name Purple** must remain there. I think the problem is because the first product have the name **item Name** and in the second product the name is start with ***item Name*** **Purple**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         if (jQuery('.items-class li:contains("item Name")').length > 0)
          { 
           var parent = jQuery('.items-class');
           var children = jQuery('.items-class').find("li");
           jQuery(children).each(function(i,e){
            if(~jQuery(e).text().indexOf("item Name Blue")){

                jQuery(parent).find('li:contains("Additional Info")').html('');  
                jQuery(parent).find('li:contains("-----")').html('');
            }
             if(~jQuery(e).text().indexOf("item Name Purple")){
                jQuery(parent).find('li:contains("Item Description")').html('');  
                jQuery(parent).find('li:contains("-------")').html('');

                jQuery(parent).find('li:contains("Additional Info")').html('');  
                jQuery(parent).find('li:contains("-----")').html('');

                jQuery(parent).find('li:contains("Color")').html('');  
                jQuery(parent).find('li:contains("-----")').html('');
            }
           else if(~jQuery(e).text().indexOf("item Name")){
                jQuery(parent).find('li:contains("Color")').html('');  
                jQuery(parent).find('li:contains("Red")').html('');
            }
          });
         }   
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but I hope this helps.

```
function removeAdditionalInfo(searchCriteria){
    var interestingTagSelector = "ul.item-options > li";
    var additionInfoHeader = "Additional Info";
    var getFilter = function(criteria){
        return function(index, item){ return (item.innerHTML === criteria); };
    };

    // find the potentially interesting li tags
    $(interestingTagSelector)

        // filter out those that are not in fact interesting
        .filter(getFilter(searchCriteria))

        // get siblings following an interesting li tag
        .nextAll()

        // ignore those not starting the additional info section
        .filter(getFilter(additionInfoHeader))

        // get siblings following the AddInfo header
        .nextAll()

        // removed them
        .remove();
}

removeAdditionalInfo("item Name");
```

Comment: thank you I don;t understand for what is this code, but if you read again my post, there are 3 items: item Name, item Name Blue and item Name Purple, how I can identify this name and if is exist do something

Answer (score 0):

the removeAdditionalInfo() function below and:

```
removeAdditionalInfo("item Name");
removeAdditionalInfo("item Name Blue");
removeAdditionalInfo("item Name Purple");
```

will remove the additional info items.

Comment: Thasn you so much, can you adapt the code for my answer, I am not so good in javascript

Comment: I *think* the code I have given you does what you are looking to do.  Either that or I did not understand what you are attempting to do.  Did you try it?